# Which HTML attribute should we use for an article's tags?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I was wondering, which HTML attribute should we use, in a list of article to put the article's tags, such as `patchnotes`, `news`, `all` etc.

I was think of putting this in the `data-*` attributes, but the purpose of this, is to filter articles according to their tags with JavaScript, for example:

When I click on the `news` tab, I want to keep visible only the articles that have for attribute value `news`.

I'm not interested in any JavaScript to make this happen, just to know which attribute would be the most relevant to make this.

Comment: Are you asking whether to do something like `data-tags="patchnotes,news,all"` or `data-patchnotes=""`, etc. and which one is better?

Comment: `data-*` would work out nicely in this application

Comment: Indeed, I would like to know which one should I use, I believe making `data-{{tagname}}` for each tag would be too long, would `data-tags="patchnotes,news"` be more easily manipulated?

Comment: If you want to keep them all in a single data attribute it would be easy with javascript to split the comma-separated list into an array to run functions on. Separating them out into individual data attributes seems trickier if there's a situation where a data attribute is present but not related to the tags.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll do like that then. Could you put this comment as an answer so I can validate it ?

Comment: This is what the `class` attribute is for.